# Maven JBoss jbpm-form-modeler deployment

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

I have ran mvn clean install and its has worked fine.

I can run mvn gwt:run and get the form modeler working with jetty.

When I take the WAR file from showcase and try to deploy it in jboss-as-7.1.1 or jboss-eap-6.2.0 it always fails deployment with following error:

```
11:52:37,365 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 10) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-form-modeler-showcase-6.0.1.Final.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"jbpm-form-modeler-showcase-6.0.1.Final\".\"jbpm-form-modeler-showcase-6.0.1.Final\".env.ErraiService is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.ErraiService]"]}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

(PS. I got jbpm-console-ng deployed no problem if that make any difference...)

Comment: Do you have some dependencies with scope `provided`in the POM? JBoss may probably be missing those dependencies that are scoped as provided in your POM so you have to look at those as that is what the error implies, that you miss some dependencies.

Comment: the war file was generated after compiling jbpm-form-modeler from github with mvn install. I went into showcase/target and took the war file from there...

Comment: try creating war with `mvn -Pjboss7 clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use fullprofile option when you make build for this module:

mvn clean install -PfullProfile

Comment: Tried that as well, no joy. Its like I'm destined not to get it working haha